# Moving a command button to a new sheet in vba

Tags: vba, button, command, move

I have a command button which does so many calculation for me. To make a user interface I need to move the button from the "calculation" sheet to the "user interface" sheet. After moving the button I need to address the inputs and outputs to "calculation" sheet. 
I used the with statement as follows:

```
  With Sheets("Calculation")
    .Range("C3", Range("C3").End(xlDown)).Clear
    .Range("X3", Range("X3").End(xlDown)).Clear
    .Range("Y3", Range("Y3").End(xlDown)).Clear
    .Range("z3", Range("z3").End(xlDown)).Clear
    .Range("AC3", Range("AC3").End(xlDown)).Clear
    .Range("B3", Range("B3").End(xlDown)).Clear
    .Range("E4", Range("E4").End(xlDown)).Clear
    .Range("A3", Range("A3").End(xlDown)).Clear
    .Range("K3", Range("K3").End(xlDown)).Clear
    .Range("D3", Range("D3").End(xlDown)).Clear

End With
```

And I had a run time error '1004' ( which says: Applicaiton -defined or object-defined error.)

I was wondering how I can call the "calculation" sheet when I have the button in "user interface" sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting the error is because of a typo in the second of your `Range` statements.  Without the `.` you're referring to the current worksheet rather than the one in your `With` statement, and the runtime error is because that range is impossible to define across 2 sheets.

```
With Sheets("Calculation")
    .Range("C3", .Range("C3").End(xlDown)).Clear
    .Range("X3", .Range("X3").End(xlDown)).Clear
    .Range("Y3", .Range("Y3").End(xlDown)).Clear
    .Range("z3", .Range("z3").End(xlDown)).Clear
    .Range("AC3", .Range("AC3").End(xlDown)).Clear
    .Range("B3", .Range("B3").End(xlDown)).Clear
    .Range("E4", .Range("E4").End(xlDown)).Clear
    .Range("A3", .Range("A3").End(xlDown)).Clear
    .Range("K3", .Range("K3").End(xlDown)).Clear
    .Range("D3", .Range("D3").End(xlDown)).Clear
End With
```

Comment: OK good. Now I have the Run-time error '91': saying that " Object variable or With block variable not set. Any idea?